# postgresql Select all rows which have max value in one column

Tags: database, postgresql, window-functions, ranking-functions

I'm new to postgresql, I have a table T like this in postgresql:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4 ID
```

C1,C2, C4 are int.
C3 is a char
C4 is essentially the version number. and can be anything between 1-N.
( For example, after one set of insert events the values in table are updated.)
ID is a char.

Question:
For a given value of ID, I want to select all rows that have highest C4 associated with them.  For example there could be N versions in the table,
I want all results corresponding to the version N.

I tried,

`select C1,C2,C3, max(C4) from T where ID = 'something';`

but it gives me error.

Please advise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

update for postgresql version 13+

the latest version of postgresql introduces [`limit ... with ties`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT)

```sql
SELECT id, c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM t
WHERE id = 'something'
ORDER BY c4 DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Specifying `WITH TIES` will return all the rows where `c4` equals the largest value in that columns, so a separate CTE with a window function is not required. If there is only 1 row where `c4` has its maximum values, then only 1 row will be returned.

---

original answer (for earlier versions of postgresql):

If there can be multiple rows for the same version number, then use the window function `RANK` in a cte and select the rows where rank equals 1

```
SELECT id, c1, c2, c3, c4 
FROM (
    SELECT 
      *
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY c4 DESC) c4rank
    FROM t
) ranked 
WHERE c4rank = 1
  AND id = 'something'
```

If you want the most recent version for all ids, just omit the condition `id = 'something'` from the above statement.

If there can only be 1 row for a given version number then use order by and limit 1

```
SELECT id, c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM t
WHERE id = 'something'
ORDER BY c4 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you want the most recent version for all ids & there can only be 1 row per (id, version) combination

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM t
WHERE id = 'something'
ORDER BY id, c4 DESC
```

Comment: there will be M number of entries per version and per file id. So I want all the rows belonging to a particular id and max/latest version.

Comment: for a single line query I can save results to txt file as follows:
`\copy (query) TO '/abc/xyz.csv' (format CSV); `  How do I pass this big complex query I'm getting syntax errors because of so many parantheses.

Comment: that's a different question, please search SO / google or ask a new question